Saving Spark ML modesl in MOJO the same as H2o
I would like to save spark ml models the same way H2o does to MOJO.
Is there a way to save spark ml models to MOJO and load them elsewhere? I have not found anything in Spark documentation but it might support this feature which I am not aware of
Thanks for any hint
